# How to ADD all files/directories except a hidden directory like .git in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

One of things we do often is to package all source code in `Dockerfile` when we build a Docker image.

```
ADD . /app
```

How can we avoid including the `.git` directory in simple way ?

I tried the Unix way of handling this using `ADD [^.]* /app/`

Complete sample:

```
docker@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/tmp/abc$ find .
.
./c
./.git
./Dockerfile
./good
./good/a1
docker@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/tmp/abc$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu

ADD [^.]* /app/
docker@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/tmp/abc$ docker build -t abc .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.096 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 04c5d3b7b065
Step 1 : ADD [^.]* /app/
d ---> 5d67603f108b
Removing intermediate container 60159dee6ac8
Successfully built 5d67603f108b
docker@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/tmp/abc$ docker run -it abc
root@1b1705dd66a2:/# ls -l app
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 staff 30 Jan 22 01:18 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 22 01:03 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 22 00:10 c
```

And secondly, it will lose the directory structure, since `good\a1` gets changed to `a1`.

Related source code in Docker is https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/eaecf741f0e00a09782d5bcf16159cc8ea258b67/builder/internals.go#L115

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You may exclude unwanted files with the help of the [.dockerignore file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

Answer (score 47):

> How can we avoid including the .git directory in simple way ?

Just create a file called `.dockerignore` in the root context folder with the following lines

```
**/.git
**/node_modules
```

With such lines Docker will exclude directories `.git` and `node_modules` from any subdirectory including root. Docker also supports a special wildcard string `**` that matches any number of directories (including zero).

> And secondly, it will lose the directory structure, since good\a1 gets changed to a1

With .dockerignore it won't

```
$ docker run -it --rm sample tree /opt/
/opt/
├── Dockerfile
├── c
│   └── no_sslv2.patch
└── good
    └── a1
        └── README

3 directories, 3 files
```

Reference to official docs: [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

Answer (score 2):

Because `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore` do not use the same syntax, I ended up running this before build:

```bash
git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard --directory > .dockerignore
printf "%s\n" .git >> .dockerignore
```

In this way I get a fresh list of actually ignored stuff from single source - what Git itself ignores. I think this is the most reliable way.

Comment: This should be the best solution. PS: why not just `echo '.git' >> .dockerignore` ?

Comment: @link89, you can. Probably initially I was thinking about `"\n%s\n"` to make sure that `.dockerignore` doesn't lack a new line character at end. And `echo` respecting escape sequences is non POSIX compliant. But in the two-liner above, you can safely use `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Add **.dockerignore** file in your root directory (syntax like the **.gitignore** file)

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to @akostadinov answer: the main difference in syntax is that Docker considers path to exclude as relative to the root.

For `.gitignore` file it's enough to write to ignore `gz` files everywhere:

```
*.gz
```

For `.dockerignore` you have to add `**` if your large archives are not in the root folder:

```
**/*.gz
```

This can help, if you have some large archive to install, but you don't want to add it as a part of the resulting image. E.g., if you have somewhere a folder `models` with archived ML models to install in your container, your code can be similar to this:

.dockerignore

```
**/*.gz
```

Mounting

```
${PROJECT_DIR}/models/:/models
```

Install in Docker

```
# Doesn't add heavy `models/*` files
ADD . ${WD_DOCKER}
# Installs from `/models` mount
pip install ... --no-index --find-links=/models
```