# Docker build extra folders

Tags: docker

I was trying to dockerize a nodejs application. I am adding code files to container using ADD command in Dockerfile. But i just noticed that folders named branches, objects, config, hooks are created automatically. Anybody out there know if its docker?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. Using ADD ./* ./folder name/ instead of ADD . ./folder name created the extra folders.

But still wonder where those folders came from.

Answer (score 1):

If your code file is in a git repo, you would have a .git subfolder that could be included by your ADD command.

That would explain the branches, hooks, ... folders.

As mentioned in "[How to ADD all files/directories except hidden directory like .git in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28083499/6309)", you can [exclude that folder with a `.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

Comment: I understand the .git folder of repo added. But, you have any idea folders named branches, objects, config, hooks are? An npm install would only create node_modules. So, where do these came from?

Comment: @Amal they should only came from a git clone. I don't know why that clone took place though

Comment: There is no git clone statement running in my docker file. Just copying files form host system to container.

Comment: @Amal but I think the ADD is the culprit: if it copies a .git folder from your host, that would explain those folder in the image built by Dockerfile. No need for a clone in the Dockerfile. There must have been a clone on your host before.

Comment: Its copying files and not cloning from git repo.